# What this jquery selector selects

Tags: jquery

What is the selection of the following query selection?

`$(".ezdz-dropzone.ezdz-accept img")`

I would assume that it selects an `img` element that is a child of element with `class="ezdz-dropzone.ezdz-accept"`.

But not sure, can we have calass attribute value with `.` in it?

Comment: It means select an element that as **both** classes `ezdz-dropdone` *and* `ezdz-accept`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ezdz-dropzone.ezdz-accept` says find an element that has a class of `ezdz-dropzone` and `ezdz-accept`.  If that is a single class, rather than two classes, you will have to escape the period with a `\`

`.ezdz-dropzone\\.ezdz-accept`

```js
console.log(
  $('.ezdz-dropzone\\.ezdz-accept')[0]
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ezdz-dropzone.ezdz-accept"></div>
```